# Is usage of Spring jdbcTemplates thread-safe

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jdbc

I have my own DAO which extends `NamedJdbcDaoSupport`. This DAO is created using the Spring framework.

I have written a small test application which accesses the DAO multiple times from the main thread without wait.

In this scenario everything works fine.

But if I access the DAO from different threads I receive the following NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:238)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:627)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:761)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:192)
    at test.DAO.loadData(DAO.java:29)
    at test.Application$1.run(Application.java:19)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In the description of the NamedJdbcDaoSupport is the following note:

> "NOTE: An instance of this class is thread-safe once configured."

So why am I receiving this NPE? If I go into the Spring source I can see that the DBConnection seems to be null. But why? Normally Spring returns with a SQLException if it is not able to get a connection from the connection pool. So an NPE should never be possible.

Can someone help me understand why the NamedJdbcDaoSupport is not thread-safe despite the comments suggesting otherwise. And what I can do?

This is my Application:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ServerContext.xml");

        DAO bean = (DAO)classPathXmlApplicationContext.getBean("dao");


        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                        bean.loadData();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my gradle script:

```
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '4.3.11.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.11.RELEASE'
        compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
        compile files('lib/ojdbc6.zip')
}
```

This is my DAO:

```
public class DAO extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport {

    public List<String> loadData() {
        Date fromDate = null;
        Date toDate = null;
        MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        namedParameters.addValue("fromDate", fromDate);
        namedParameters.addValue("toDate", toDate);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
        return getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(sql, namedParameters, new RowMapper<String>() {
            @Override
            public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

                return null;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And this is my Spring context:

```
<!-- Database -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"/>
    <property name="user" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="passwort"/>
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />    
    <property name="connectionCacheName" value="my_connection_pool" />
    <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
        <value>
            MinLimit: 10
            MaxLimit: 10
            InitialLimit: 10
            ValidateConnection: true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dao" class="test.DAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Why is the private field there?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I've added code of the several files. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It seams that it is a problem with the datasource. The apache commons Basic Datasource works fine